# Persisting document id for use in .valueChanges() gives two different ids

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

In the [angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md), it explains that in order to persist a document Id for use with `.valueChanges()`, you should create one with `afs.createId()`.

```
export class AppComponent {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
    // .valueChanges() is simple. It just returns the 
    // JSON data without metadata. If you need the 
    // doc.id() in the value you must persist it your self
    // or use .snapshotChanges() instead. See the addItem()
    // method below for how to persist the id with
    // valueChanges()
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
  addItem(name: string) {
    // Persist a document id
    const id = this.afs.createId();
    const item: Item = { id, name };
    this.itemsCollection.add(item);
  }
}
```

When added to the collection the item's id and the key it's stored under differ, however. Is this correct? Is there a way to set the key when adding to a collection so that they match? I sense that having two ids might be a headache in future.

I know that `.snapshotChanges()` provides the metadata, but I'm streaming the items in my project, and mapping snapshot changes causes each entry to re-render in angular. I think this is what the docs warn about when they say the following:

> **snapshotChanges()**
>
> ...
>
> When would you not use it? - When you need a more complex data structure than an array or if you need to process changes as they occur.

Comment: I ended up using snapshotChanges() on my collection that lists a bunch of projects to get the ID. When you say it causes each entry to re-render, what's happening exactly? I think I'm experiencing that when using snapshotChanges() with a AngularFirestoreDocument and can't figure out why.

Comment: My issue is this: each item has a sub-collection. When an item is rendered in an ItemComponent, it fetches a sub-collection. When a new item is added to the list, it fetches the sub-collection for every item all over again. I checked and it reinitializes a component for each item every time one is added. In my mind it would just add a new component for the newly added item. I might be making a basic error here that's not specific to angularfire2...

Comment: @MegaTron I managed to fix my issue with trackBy in *ngFor ([docs](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_for_directive.html)). It prevents my components being reinitialized when my items array updates, maybe you can find an answer for your issue there too.

Comment: Does that mean if you didn't use track by, that the client would need to 'read' the data of every item on the page each time a new one is added? I think CloudStore pricing is based on reads.

Comment: Not entirely sure, there's a flag in the snapShot saying it's "fromCache" when a component's reinitialized but requesting the same data, not sure if that saves a trip to the server, but I'm guessing so. Using trackBy improves performance on the client regardless because angular doesn't need to reinitialize all the previous components when inserting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the documentation states that, and I would appreciate if anybody can give an explanation.

I solved the problem explicitly set the id when creating the document as follow:

```
 public addSubBudget = (bdgtId, description: string) => {
   const coord = BUDGET_COLLECTION + '/' + bdgtId + '/sub-budgets';
   const subBudgetCollRef = this.afs.collection<SubBudget>(coord);
   const id = this.afs.createId();
   const subBudget: SubBudget = { id, description };
   return subBudgetCollRef.doc(id).set(subBudget);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future references, the documentation had a bug. This is how an Id should be persisted:

```
addItem(name: string) {
    // Persist a document id
    const id = this.afs.createId();
    const item: Item = { id, name };
    this.itemsCollection.doc(id).set(item);
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/1539/files